# Error in using juju bootstrap google < name> command

Tags: kubernetes, juju

Hey I'm new to kubernetes  trying to implement the kubernete federation and was able to configure the aws and GCP credentials and got a successful output while testing for AWS but when I was trying to use it for GCP  got stuck with  an error

command: juju bootstrap google mycloud

ERROR fetching hosted model spaces: adding subnet "10.142.0.0/20": subnet "10.142.0.0/20" already exists

ERROR failed to bootstrap model: subprocess encountered error code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like subnet "10.142.0.0/20" already exists in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) you can find all your networks and subnets in the GCP by running a command in the Google Cloud Shell

```
gcloud  compute networks subnets list
```

or find it in Networking > VPC network > VPC networks  section of the GUI

It looks like you use default GCP subnet

> us-east1  default     10.142.0.0/20   10.142.0.1

you can delete all default subnets from GCP, or try to configure networking in your  config file

```
~/.juju/environments.yaml
```